# NullPointerException in a thread java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am experimenting with the multithreading in java and I have a nullPointerException. I try to pass a parameter in my thread and i missed up somewhere but i dunno where. I hope someone can point me where i was stupid :).
I wrote this class :

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
 private String myBelovedParam = null;

public MyThread (String param){
    myBelovedParam = param;
}
public void run(){
    try {
        AnotherClass.anotherFunction(myBelovedParam );

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

And I called it like that :

```
Thread myThread = new MyThread (theParameterIWant);
    myThread.start();
```

Thanks all and have a good day !

I edit my post (i change the name of everything and i forgot to change some. that why the name of some thread was different).

Here is the error i get in my console :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.NullPointerException
at play.classloading.enhancers.ControllersEnhancer$ControllerInstrumentation.isActionCallAllowed(ControllersEnhancer.java:187)
at anotherFunction(AnotherClass.java)
at threads.myThread.run(myThread.java:21)
```

I tried to change null by empty String -> no Effect
When i debug i can see clearly that theParameterIWant is not null.

Comment: Read the error message. It'll tell you where the NPE occurs.

Comment: what happens if you intialize `myBelovedParam` with an empty string instead of null? also maybe `theParameterIWant` is null

Comment: Some misguiding codes are there: why purgeThread.start() instead of myThread.start(). Another point you are passing the parameter to anotherfunction where you might using by taking the reference of the parameter where might throw null. Please provide the AnotherClass.AnotherFunction detail as well. Please keep a note: function name should start with lowercase.

Comment: <<public class MyThread1  extends Thread{
  private String myBelovedParam = null;

  public MyThread1(String param){
      myBelovedParam = param;
  }
  public void run(){
      try {
       ThreadTest.showSomething(myBelovedParam );

      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Thread myThread = new MyThread1("I'm here");
     myThread.start();
 }
 
 static class ThreadTest {
  static void showSomething(String displayStr){
   System.out.println(displayStr);
  }
 }
}>>
This just worked fine for me.